# LINQ OrderBy. Does it always return the same ordered list?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-objects

I was trying out a simple OrderBy statement.

The target data to order is something like below:

```
[
  {"id":40, "description":"aaa", "rate":1},
  {"id":1,  "description":"bbb", "rate":1},
  {"id":4,  "description":"ccc", "rate":2},
  {"id":19, "description":"aaa", "rate":1} 
]
```

Then I order items by the rate property.

The odd thing is that if I 'order' them, it 'skips' some items by a given offset and then 'take' only portion of the data.

*For example,*

```
var result = items.OrderBy(i => i.rate);
var result = result.Skip(2);
var result = result.Take(2);
```

The result looks fine for the most of it, but the 'edge case' item is not returned at all.

*For example,*

if the first result came back as

```
    [{"id":40, "description":"aaa", "rate":1}, {"id":1, "description":"bbb", "rate":1}]
```

the second result comes back like

```
    [{"id":1, "description":"bbb", "rate":1}, {"id":4, "description":"ccc", "rate":2}]
```

Item "id: 19" has not been returned with the second query call. Instead item "id: 1" has returned twice.

My guess is that the SQL OrderBy statement doesn't produce the same ordered list every single time OrderBy orders by a given property, but the exact order within a group that shares the same property can change.

What is the exact mechanism under the hood?

Comment: If you don't specify the order then there is no guarantee. If you specify several columns, e.g. `order by rate, description`, then it will order by `rate` and then, where `rate` values repeat,  `description`. There may still be multiple rows with equal values for both `rate` and `description` and their order would remain unspecified. `id` is often used as a tie-breaker to ensure a stable order: `order by rate, description, id`.

Comment: A practical reason for why the order might be different: Some quick sort algorithms randomize the choice of the pivot.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Short answer:** LINQ to Objects uses a stable sort algorithm, so we can say that it is deterministic, and LINQ to SQL depends on the database implementation of Order By that is usually nondeterministic.

A deterministic sort algorithm is one that have always the same behavior on different runs.

In you example, you have duplicates in your OrderBy clause. For a guaranteed and predicted sort, one of the order clauses or the combination of order clauses must be *unique*.

In LINQ, you can achieve it by adding another OrderBy clause to refer your unique property, like in
`items.OrderBy(i => i.Rate).ThenBy(i => i.ID)`.

**Long answer:**

LINQ to Objects uses a stable sort, as documented in this link: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx).

In LINQ to SQL, it depends on the sort algorithm of the underlying database and it is usually an unstable sort, like in MS SQL Server ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)).

In a stable sort, if the keys of two elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved. In contrast, an unstable sort does not preserve the order of elements that have the same key.

[image: Wikipedia example]

So, for LINQ to SQL, the sorting is usually nondeterministic because the **RDMS** (Relational Database Management System, like MS SQL Server) may directly use a unstable sort algorithm with a random pivot selection or the randomness can be related with which row the database happens to access first in the file system.

For example, imagine that the size of a page in the file system can hold up to 4 rows.

The page will be full if you insert the following data:

```
     Page 1
| Name | Value |
|------|-------|
|   A  |   1   |
|   B  |   2   |
|   C  |   3   |
|   D  |   4   |
```

If you need to insert a new row, the RDMS has two options:

1. Create a new page to allocate the new row.
2. Split the current page in two pages. So the first page will hold the Names **A** and **B** and the second page will hold **C** and **D**.

Suppose that the RDMS chooses option 1 (to reduce index fragmentation). If you insert a new row with Name **C** and Value **9**, you will get:

```
     Page 1              Page 2
| Name | Value |    | Name | Value |
|------|-------|    |------|-------|
|   A  |   1   |    |   C  |   9   |
|   B  |   2   |    |      |       |
|   C  |   3   |    |      |       |
|   D  |   4   |    |      |       |
```

*Probably*, the OrderBy clause in column **Name** will return the following:

```
| Name | Value |
|------|-------|
|   A  |   1   |
|   B  |   2   |
|   C  |   3   |
|   C  |   9   | -- Value 9 appears after because it was at another page
|   D  |   4   |
```

Now, suppose that the **RDMS** chooses option 2 (to increase the insert performance in a storage system with many spindles). If you insert a new row with Name **C** and Value **9**, you will get:

```
     Page 1              Page 2
| Name | Value |    | Name | Value |
|------|-------|    |------|-------|
|   A  |   1   |    |   C  |   3   |
|   B  |   2   |    |   D  |   4   |
|   C  |   9   |    |      |       |
|      |       |    |      |       |
```

*Probably*, the OrderBy clause in column **Name** will return the following:

```
| Name | Value |
|------|-------|
|   A  |   1   |
|   B  |   2   |
|   C  |   9   |  -- Value 9 appears before because it was at the first page
|   C  |   3   | 
|   D  |   4   |
```

**Regarding your example:**

I believe that you have mistyped something in your question, because you have used `items.OrderBy(i => i.rate).Skip(2).Take(2);` and the first result do not show a row with `Rate = 2`. This is not possible since the `Skip` will ignore the first two rows and they have `Rate = 1`, so your output must show the row with `Rate = 2`.

You've tagged your question with `database`, so I believe that you are using LINQ to SQL. In this case, results can be nondeterministic and you could get the following:

Result 1:

```
[{"id":40, "description":"aaa", "rate":1},
 {"id":4, "description":"ccc", "rate":2}]
```

Result 2:

```
[{"id":1, "description":"bbb", "rate":1},
 {"id":4, "description":"ccc", "rate":2}]
```

If you had used `items.OrderBy(i => i.rate).ThenBy(i => i.ID).Skip(2).Take(2);` then the only possible result would be:

```
[{"id":40, "description":"aaa", "rate":1},
 {"id":4, "description":"ccc", "rate":2}]
```

Comment: Its worth noting that LINQ to objects uses a stable sort for OrderBy, but a linq query that is converted to SQL will use its data sources implementation of ORDER BY.

Comment: Thanks @RyanDansie, I've added your note to my answer.