# LINQ - Will FirstOrDefault() always return the same record?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

if I have the following 'User' table

```
UserName UserID
-------- ------
abc      1
xyz      2
pqr      2
```

and the following linq query:

```
_context.User.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserID).FirstOrDefault();
```

will the result always be consistent?

as in will I always get either user with UserName 'xyz' or user with UserName 'pqr' or will it be random?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ OrderBy. Does it always return the same ordered list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922348/linq-orderby-does-it-always-return-the-same-ordered-list)

Comment: Just to add that it's very bad form for what is 'normally' a unique record id (UserID) to have duplicates.   This really should be enforced by your database (by making it a primary key, in the case of most databases).

Comment: clarification: do you *genuinely* have 2 users with the same `UserIdD` value in the `User` table? that sounds like a missing key constraint, frankly

Comment: Do you want a <linq> or <sql> answer?

Comment: @sayahimad will definitely check the thread out when I can... unfortunately it didn't appear when I was doing my research and hence, created a new post.. Thank you..

Comment: @Neil I agree.. and no this is just a sample table I created for the sake of this question.. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcGravell no, I do not.. this is just a sample.. in actuality I have a column CurrentVersion and yes there are duplicates in it.. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To be a bit snarky, yes, `FirstOrDefault` will *always* return the "first" item in the sequence (or a default value if there are no items). What *could* change is what is presented by `OrderByDescending`. You have two items with the same `UserId` value, so when you ask for items ordered by that value, SQL makes no guarantee that the order of the items with the same ID will be the same every time.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it will not be random, after using OrderByDescending on UserID from table Users having duplicate UserID, the other dependent column will appear in the final list in the same order as it was in the User Table.

for eg.  If this was the order in the table

```
UserName UserID
-------- ------
abc      1
pqr      2
xyz      2
```

and the following linq query:

```
_context.User.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Will give Output : user with pqr

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I read the following in [Enumerable.OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1)

> This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved. In contrast, an unstable sort does not preserve the order of elements that have the same key.

So, since this is a stable sort, the result of an IEnumerable OrderBy will always be the same.

However, although you didn't tell so, because you are using `_context.User`, I assume that the table is in a database management system. The result depends on your DBMS.

[Queryable.OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Queryable_OrderBy__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___) says:

> The query behavior that occurs as a result of executing an expression tree that represents calling OrderBy(IQueryable, Expression>) depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter. The expected behavior is that it sorts the elements of source based on the key obtained by invoking keySelector on each element of source.

This is a difficult way to say the the result of sorting two elements depends on the DBMS that you use. If you want to be certain that you have always the same sorted result, you'll have to order ThenBy a 2nd element, and if needed a 3rd, until you are certain that you are sorting on unique values.

Answer (score -3):

Caveat: I am assuming here that the `UserId` column on the `User` table is a PKID and is unique.

You are issuing an ordered query, so yes: it will always return the `pqr` record (until the data changes, obviously). The SQL will be something like:

```sql
select top 1 *
from User
order by UserId desc
```

but you can find out the *actual* SQL by checking with a SQL trace.

If you didn't have the `OrderByDescending`: there would be no guarantees.

Comment: I believe that you are incorrect, since the ID is not unique and both xyz and pqr will be at the "same position" (since both have UserID 2 and thus it is no ID at all) of the order by. I believe that it depends on the source of the data. If it will run on something like `List` the result will be stable. If it will be returned from a DB, it is dependant on the sorting of a used DB server. Both orders of the mentioned record will be valid, thus one cannot be certain of the outcome.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain you are correct there.  There are 2 records with the same user id, and the database is free to return them in any order, as long as they are matching the query.  For a particular database server (and version), you may be correct, but it's not a guarantee.

Comment: @Matyas I was unspokenly assuming that `UserId` in the `User` table is a PKID and therefore unique